# Error when using permutation_importance in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn

I am writing a python code to provide local feature importance to explain outlier scores. I am running into an error: raise ValueError( ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1000, 1]

```
*Traceback : _Traceback (most recent call last): File "/tmp/sessions/827ab297d3bdaadf/main.py", line 44, in importance = permutation_importance(isolation_forest, df.iloc[i].values.reshape(1, -1), y=np.zeros(df.shape[0]), scoring='neg_mean_squared_error') File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/inspection/_permutation_importance.py", line 257, in permutation_importance baseline_score = _weights_scorer(scorer, estimator, X, y, sample_weight) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/inspection/_permutation_importance.py", line 19, in _weights_scorer return scorer(estimator, X, y) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 219, in call return self._score( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 267, in _score return self._sign self._score_func(y_true, y_pred, self._kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_regression.py", line 442, in mean_squared_error y_type, y_true, y_pred, multioutput = _check_reg_targets( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_regression.py", line 100, in check_reg_targets check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 387, in check_consistent_length raise ValueError( ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1000, 1]*
```

````py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance


# Set the random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)

# Generate the data
num_sensors = 5
num_samples = 1000
data = np.random.randn(num_samples, num_sensors)
for i in range(1, num_sensors):
    data[:, i] += data[:, i-1]

# Add some anomalies to the data
anomaly_indices = [100, 300, 500, 700]
anomaly_magnitudes = [10, 5, 7, 12]
for i, mag in zip(anomaly_indices, anomaly_magnitudes):
    data[i:i+5, 0] += mag

# Convert the data to a pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[f"sensor_{i}" for i in range(num_sensors)])

# Initialize the isolation forest model
isolation_forest = IsolationForest(n_estimators=100, contamination='auto', random_state=42)

# Fit the model to your data
isolation_forest.fit(df)

# Predict the anomalies
anomalies = isolation_forest.predict(df)

# Get the indices of anomalies
anomaly_indices = np.where(anomalies == -1)[0]

# Determine local feature importance for each anomaly
for i in anomaly_indices:
    # Get the prediction score for the anomaly
    score = isolation_forest.score_samples(df.iloc[i].values.reshape(1, -1))
    print( df.iloc[i].values.reshape(1, -1))
    # Compute the permutation feature importance for the anomaly
    importance = permutation_importance(isolation_forest, df.iloc[i].values.reshape(1, -1), y=np.zeros(df.shape[0]), scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')

    # Print the feature importance for the anomaly
    print(f"Anomaly detected in row {i}")
    print(f"Prediction score: {score}")
    print("Feature importance:")
    #for feature, importance_score in zip(df.columns, importance.importances_mean):
        #print(f"{feature}: {importance_score}")
    print("="*50)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stems from the line:

```py
importance = permutation_importance(isolation_forest, df.iloc[i].values.reshape(1, -1), y=np.zeros(df.shape[0]), scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
```

Here, the y parameter should be a vector of length 1, as the permutation_importance function requires the target values (y) to be the same length as the input data (X).

The solution is to replace

```py
y=np.zeros(df.shape[0]) with y=np.zeros(1).
```

I hope this helps!